# Pentaho report designer ,Could not connect to HTTP server on ''local host''

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

Pentaho version -- prd-ce-3.9.0-GA  (database connection MySQL)

I am getting the error

```
Could not connect to HTTP server on ''local host''
```

I tried with `htttps//127.0.0.1:8080/pentaho` and `htttps//192.7.*.*:8080/pentaho`(my local machine IP) but I failed ,I am getting the error continuously.

I tried many things, I am not login to any server.

Thanks!!

Comment: I have the screenshot also

Comment: Have you checked your MySQl is up and running ?

Comment: My sql is connected and running, I am running the reports in Pentaho by connecting to MySQL and it's running.

Comment: htttps//127.0.0.1:8080/pentaho. Check this there is ttt in it and also there is no colon present.

Comment: Sir,I just wrote it by myself that's why spelling mistake...This is all in proper format..

Comment: http://localhost:8080/pentaho               ...............     http://127.0.0.1:8080/pentaho